# Mutate string originating from React state

Tags: javascript

Let's say for some delicate reason I have the following react state:

```
{ superGreeting: 'Hello!!!' }
```

Now, assume I have this complicated operation that basically takes the superGreeting string and works on it, in the end replacing a character at a specific position. New state then should be:

```
{ superGreeting: 'Hullo!!!' }
```

So, there would be my action:

```
action = (index) => {
  var { superGreeting: newGreeting } = this.state;
  newGreeting[index] = 'u';
  this.setState({superGreeting: newGreeting});
}
```

Unfortunatelly, such approach does not work and ends with:
`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '1' of string 'Hello!!!'`, indicating this line as the offending one: `newGreeting[index] = 'u'`

I use react.js, ES6, no redux, no mobx, no immutable.js. Thought that the issue is caused by the string still being related/used by the soon-to-be-previous state, so I thought that creating a copy would work (I tried `newGreeting = newGreeting.toString()`, `'' + newGreeting`, `${newGreeting}`, `''.concat(newGreeting)`, without any success). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable. Your example can be trimmed down to

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    var str = 'Hullo!!!';
    str[1] = 'e';
})();
```

If you want to mutate a string, you'll need to create a new string, e.g.

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    var str = 'Hullo!!!';
    str = str.slice(0, 1) + 'e' + str.slice(2);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in JS are immutable, but you can turn it into an array, work on it, then join it back together.. also there are string functions like `substr` and `replace` which return a new string if those are applicable.

```
var split = superGreeting.split('')
split[index] = 'u'
var newGreeting = split.join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here does not have anything to do with react. Strings in javascript are immutable.

You  could create the following helper function:

```
var replaceCharAt = function(str, index, c) {
    return str.slice(0, index) + c + str.slice(index+1)
}
```

so that

```
replaceCharAt('012', 1, 'x') === '0x2'
```

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed the example.